# PHP date ISO 8601 date Timezone

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime

I have this date returned from payment gateway

```
2014-05-15T08:40:52+01:00
```

I got 2014-05-15T08:40:52 but i am unable to identify meaning of timezone `+01:00`

My location timezone is UTC−06:00 (CT)

Servers location time zone is UTC−02:00

My payment gateway time zone UTC−05:00 (EST)

What is the meaning of `+01:00` after adding/without adding it to my timezones? How can i tell to my website user that he/she successfully completed payment process at XX date and Time...

Comment: The +01:00 means offset from UTC.

Answer (score 3):

**[ISO 8601 Specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime-970915.html)**

> The formats are as follows. Exactly the components shown here must be
>   present, with exactly this punctuation. Note that the "T" appears
>   literally in the string, to indicate the beginning of the time
>   element, as specified in ISO 8601.

```
   Year:
      YYYY (eg 1997)
   Year and month:
      YYYY-MM (eg 1997-07)
   Complete date:
      YYYY-MM-DD (eg 1997-07-16)
   Complete date plus hours and minutes:
      YYYY-MM-DDThh:mmTZD (eg 1997-07-16T19:20+01:00)
   Complete date plus hours, minutes and seconds:
      YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssTZD (eg 1997-07-16T19:20:30+01:00)
   Complete date plus hours, minutes, seconds and a decimal fraction of a second
      YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sTZD (eg 1997-07-16T19:20:30.45+01:00)
```

> where:

```
     YYYY = four-digit year
     MM   = two-digit month (01=January, etc.)
     DD   = two-digit day of month (01 through 31)
     hh   = two digits of hour (00 through 23) (am/pm NOT allowed)
     mm   = two digits of minute (00 through 59)
     ss   = two digits of second (00 through 59)
     s    = one or more digits representing a decimal fraction of a second
     TZD  = time zone designator (Z or +hh:mm or -hh:mm)
```

> This profile defines two ways of handling time zone offsets:
>
> 1.Times are expressed in UTC (Coordinated Universal Time), with a special UTC designator ("Z").
>
> 2.Times are expressed in local time, together with a time zone offset in hours and minutes.
>
> A time zone offset of "+hh:mm" indicates that
>   the date/time uses a local time zone which is "hh" hours and "mm"
>   minutes ahead of UTC.
>
> A time zone offset of "-hh:mm" indicates that
>   the date/time uses a local time zone which is "hh" hours and "mm"
>   minutes behind UTC.

This section answers your question

> A time zone offset of "+hh:mm" indicates that the date/time uses a local time zone which is "hh" hours and "mm" minutes ahead of UTC.

**TL;DR**

The date that you are seeing is in a Time Zone 1 hour ahead of UTC, regardless of what time is it at your server and what time is it at the payment gateway. The time that it *did* return is 1 hour ahead of UTC which stands anywhere in the world and in any time zone.